# Is it just me or is the quality of questions on SF declining?

Tags: discussion, doomed

Within the past few months, I have noticed a definite decline in the quality and type of questions.  It seems that SF is handling a lot of programming, or beginning/home users that really should be addressed in other SE sites and not asked here at all.  After all, I thought that SF is supposed to be the site for "professional sysadmin" stuff.

Is more aggressive moderation the answer here?

Comment: Wow, like @Iain said, you're only noticing it now?  If you want to be a moderator, you should be paying more attention.

Comment: I am paying attention but was trying to at least be just a little less blunt.  Its become far worse since that change the google that was made awhile ago.

Answer (score 12):

You only noticed this in the *past few months*. Which stone have you been hiding under for the last couple of years or more?

Perception is reality. For all of their high falluten words about quality and community SE really only care about footfall. That's why their efforts to date to improve the quality of SE have been so pink-and-fluffy and largely ineffective.

The only way to solve the problem is to raise the barrier and that requires more, firmer moderation. The community needs to wrest SF back from the cluless and cease being the HellDesk of SO that it has become.

More, faster, firmer moderation is the only way forward. Vote for [me](https://serverfault.com/election/4#post-645738) and vote for the [Noob](https://serverfault.com/election/4#post-645712) you know it makes sense.

Comment: I was just trying to be a little less blunt and softer.  But it appears that I am not the only one who has noticed.  I try to do what I can from a review point and question downgrading.  And I strongly agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 4):

More aggressive moderation both on the main site (to close crap) and on meta (to close the whining that comes from closing crap) is the only solution to fix this problem.

No more pink-and-fluff from SE. No more summer of love, winter of cuddle or whatever.

Comment: Winter of cuddle? Must be something you only get up there in Norway...